# Singular Value Decomposition gives a row permutated matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I want to find the SVD of the following matrix.
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$$

The singular values of the above matrix are $\sqrt{17}$,$1$. The following results are posted here in order to make this question shorter.

$$AA^T=\begin{bmatrix}5&6&4\\6&8&6\\4&6&5\end{bmatrix}$$
Eigen values of $AA^T$=$\{0,1,17\}$

Eigen vectors of $AA^T$=$\{\begin{bmatrix}-2\\3\\-2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\3\end{bmatrix}\}$

$$A^TA=\begin{bmatrix}9&8\\8&9\end{bmatrix}$$
Eigen values of $A^TA$=$\{1,17\}$

Eigen vectors of $A^TA$=$\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$

Therefore, we can write the U,V,W matrices as follows.

$$U=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{-2}{\sqrt{17}}\\
\frac{4}{\sqrt{34}}&0&\frac{3}{\sqrt{17}}\\
\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{-2}{\sqrt{17}}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$W=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{17}&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
$$V=V^T=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

My problem is that why in here, $$A\neq UWV^T$$
$$UWV^T=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\2&2\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$$
which is a row permuted version of A.

This problem won't occur if I multiplied the eigenvector of $AA^T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue of $1$ by $(-1)$.(i.e; by using $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ instead of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$). Both of those eigenvectors are correct for the eigenvalue $1$ of that matrix. So, my problem is how do we identify such occasions when obtaining the SVD?

Comment: Your eigenvector for the eigenvalue zero does not work. $[2,-3,2]$ or $[-2,3,-2]$ does work. After you have the first eigenvector basis, you get the second easier following the relation $U^TA=WV^T$ or $A^TU=VW$. So essentially take the integer eigenvectors, apply $A^T$ and then (ortho-)normalize the resulting set.

Comment: Thanks @LutzLehmann I edited my eigenvector of $AA^T$. It was a typo because I have put the value right in the matrix U. So your solution is to instead of finding two eigenvector basis first, find one and obtain the other from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Lutz Lehmann's comment above I figured out the way to obtain the SVD without worrying about the problem I previously faced. I am posting my answer here so that it would be a help to anyone who has the same problem.

In the SVD, we express the matrix A as a product of 3 matrices which I am denoting as U, W, $V^T$. In this less problematic method, what we have to first do is obtaining the $A^TA$.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\implies A^TA=\begin{bmatrix}9&8\\8&9\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Then we obtain the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of $A^TA$ as follows.

$det(A^TA-\lambda I)=det(\begin{bmatrix}9-\lambda&8\\8&9-\lambda\end{bmatrix})=0$

$\implies (1-\lambda)(17-\lambda)=0$

$\therefore \lambda=\{17,1\}$

When $\lambda = 17,$

eigenvector = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

$\therefore$ normalized eigenvector when ($\lambda = 17$) = $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}=v_1$

When $\lambda = 1,$

eigenvector = $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

$\therefore$ normalized eigenvector when ($\lambda = 1$) = $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}=v_2$

---

The corresponding singular value would be $\{\sigma_1=\sqrt{17},\sigma_2=1\}$.

Using the above results, we can write W and V as follows.

$$W=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{17}&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$V=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Now we can obtain the columns of U without explicitly calculating the eigenvectors of $AA^T$ as follows.

Simply use the following relation,

**$$Av_i=\sigma_i u_i, \forall i$$**

$$\therefore Av_1=\sigma_1 u_1$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}= \sqrt{17} u_1$$

$$\therefore \begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}=\sqrt{17} u_1\implies u_1=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}\\\frac{4}{\sqrt{34}}\\\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Also, $Av_2=\sigma_2 u_2$

$$\therefore \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}= 1 u_2 \implies u_2 = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

---

$$\therefore U = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{4}{\sqrt{34}}&0\\
\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

So, the SVD of A is,

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{4}{\sqrt{34}}&0\\
\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{17}&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

---

The above is the reduced SVD. In any case if you want to obtain the full SVD, all you have to do is obtain the normalized eigenvector of $AA^T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue of $0$ and, put that as the third column of the above U matrix. Also, remember to add another row of zeros to the W matrix as its third row.

The above method can be applied to any given matrix to obtain the singular value decomposition.